# How to reverse proxy sse requests using nestjs

Tags: nestjs, reverse-proxy, server-sent-events

I have an external web application which has backend (nodeJs) and client (Vue).
now we want to use this web application behind a reverse-proxy (not Nginx, since we implemented an internal logic to bypass some logic).

We found the application is using sse to update the UI so now we also should support sse proxy requests. we using NestJs so proxy all http requests working, now we get stuck on the sse requests.

This is how we implemented the `sse` controller

```
@Sse('/rest/push')
  async proxyPushMessages(@Res({ passthrough: true }) response: FastifyReply, @Req() request: any) {
    const sseStream = this.sseProxyService.proxySSE(request);
    response.header('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
    response.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    response.header('Connection', 'keep-alive');
    sseStream.subscribe(
      (messageEvent) => {
        return response.send(`data: ${messageEvent.data}`);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('SSE Error:', error);
        return response.send(`data: ${error}`);
      },
      () => {
        return response.send(`data: ${'SSE stream closed'}`);
      },
    );
  }
```

this is the sse proxy service which proxy the requests to the app backend

```
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { FastifyRequest, Injectable } from '@transmit-security/bindid-services-core-service';
import { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';
const baseWorkflowsUrl = process.env.WORKFLOWS_SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:5678';

@Injectable()
export class SSEProxyService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}
  private buildUrl(url: string): string {
    return `${baseWorkflowsUrl}${url}`;
  }
  proxySSE(req: FastifyRequest): Observable<MessageEvent> {
    const { url, method, headers } = req;
    const reqObject: AxiosRequestConfig = {
      url: this.buildUrl(url),
      withCredentials: true,
      responseType: 'text',
      method,
      headers: headers as any,
    };
    return this.httpService.request(reqObject).pipe(map((response) => new MessageEvent('message', response.data)));
  }
}
```

looks like the push requests are resolved but still the ui is not updated.
what i am missing?

attached browser network snapshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i solved it by using `http-proxy-middleware` npm lib handle it under the hood.
code example

```
    this.proxy = createProxyMiddleware({
      target: process.env.WORKFLOWS_SERVER_URL,
      secure: false,
      ws: true,
      onProxyRes: (proxyRes: any, req: any, res: any) => {
        res.setHeader(
          'Content-Security-Policy',
          `default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';block-all-mixed-content;font-src 'self' https: data:;frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self' ${process.env.WORKFLOWS_SERVER_URL} 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ;script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests`,
        );
      },
    });
  }
```